# Strange performance of multi qplots to a figure in R when parameter of qplot includes list

Tags: r, ggplot2

Aim: save multi qplots into a figure. 
The point is there is a list parameter to loop (see code. It's more clear!). The output is different as I expected. They are the same!

```
# Make y be a list containing different values.
y <- list()
for (j in 1:6) {
    y[[j]] <- rnorm(10)
}

# plot multi qplots into one figure
plots <- list()  # new empty list
for (i in 1:6) {
    p1 = qplot(1:10, y[[i]],  main = i)
    plots[[i]] <- p1  # add each plot into plot list
}
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

[image: The figure]

The code is revised from http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2852_379274d7c5734f979e106dcf019ec46c.html

There is `y` partly: (to illustrate they are different!). The figure only used the last one in y. It's strange.

```
[[1]]
 [1]  2.01846525 -2.32504052 -1.07201485 -0.21105479  0.25706024  0.50934754
 [7]  0.39844954  0.18110421  1.03368602  0.01185971

[[2]]
 [1]  0.01824317 -1.51801208  1.68385158 -0.30159404 -0.34894329  0.62840458
 [7] -0.45447576  1.18625774 -0.36671100 -0.05502285
...
[[6]]
 [1]  0.1134854  0.1806742 -0.9491033  0.7279389 -0.2193326  0.1595183 -1.1751557
 [8] -0.4416456 -0.7074360 -0.3887882
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to with with the lazy exaluation of parameters passed to `qplot`. The values aren't actually resolved till you print the plot. At that point, the value if `i` is just 6 after the looping. A better strategy would be

```
plots <- lapply(1:6, function(i) {
    force(i) #required if you didn't have main=i to force the evaluation of i
    qplot(1:10, y[[i]],  main = i)
})
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

Comment: The answer is really what I unexpected. Of course, it's correct. I almost cannot recognise any difference between lapply and for loop in this situation.

Comment: The difference is that functions called in `lapply` have a different environment whereas the for loop evaluates all parameters in the same environment.

Comment: Is there any other utility for this kind of usage of lapply? Thank you.